# VBA Transforming Table of Data

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to accomplish the task as shown in the image with macros.

[image]

```
Sub test()

Dim ws, out As Worksheet
Dim cnt As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set out = Worksheets("Sheet2")

out.Range("A1") = "Dept"

cnt = 2

For i = 2 To 4 ' row
    For j = 2 To 4 ' column

        out.Range("A" & cnt) = ws.Range("A" & i)
        out.Range("B" & cnt) = ws.Cells(1, j).Value
        out.Range("C" & cnt) = ws.Cells(i, j).Value

        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Wondering if there is a method of accomplishing the above task without using loops?

Comment: That's an "unpivot" operation. If your hypothetical data is actually coming from a SQL Server database, you can unpivot it at the source. Heck, if that's the case then the source it quite likely pivoting already-normalized data. If not... I don't think so. In any case, this question is probably too broad for this site - consider presenting your code on [codereview.se], where improving working code is the mandate of every reviewer.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
Sub Transpose(ByVal WhatToTranspose As Range, ByVal WhereToPaste As Range)
    Dim col As Integer  'loop through columns
    Dim row As Integer  'loop through rows
    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim b() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    a() = WhatToTranspose

    For row = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
    For col = 2 To UBound(a, 2)
        If a(row, col) > 0 Then
          i = i + 1
          ReDim Preserve b(1 To 3, 1 To i)
          b(1, i) = a(row, 1)
          b(2, i) = a(1, col)
          b(3, i) = a(row, col)
        End If
      Next
    Next
    b() = Application.Transpose(b())
    WhereToPaste.Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)).Value = b()
End Sub
```

and should be called like

```
Sub Caller()
Transpose Range("A1:D4"), Range("F1")
End Sub
```

*NOTE: i am posting this answer without testing. Should you have problems I will try to edit this post later*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2013 and later, you may use Power Query to transform such data in the desired format. You just need to unpivot the date columns.
Also it is dynamic enough so that if you add data in the data table later, you just need to refresh the table returned by the power query and new data will be shown in the table.

To know the steps, watch this short demo video.

https://www.screencast.com/t/8beXtAJcgX5